# Copying from local in Hadoop not working

Tags: hadoop

```
 hadoopuser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop/bin$ hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal usr/local/tmp/gutenberg /home/hadoopuser/gutenberg
 15/06/04 05:02:49 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
 copyFromLocal: /home/hadoopuser/gutenberg: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

The target directory does not exist in HDFS. Create it using:

`hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /home/hadoopuser`

where the `-p` option is to create parent directories as needed.

Also, I think you missed `/` in your local input path. It must be `/usr/local/tmp/gutenberg` instead of `usr/local/tmp/gutenberg`